# We construct 4-digit numbers, which are chosen from any of the following seven digits: 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

So basically, we construct 4-digit numbers, which are chosen from any of the following seven digits: 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9.

> What is the probability of a number having no digit ‘7’ and containing two or more identical digits?

*4 digit numbers that starts with 0s count too, like 0177*

For the moment I have the number of 4 digits numbers that uses these 7 digits : $7^4 = 2401$.

Then I have the number of 4 digits numbers with at least 2 identical numbers which is : $2401 - 840 = 1561$

*the 840 comes from the $P(n,r) = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$*

Then I have the number of 4 digit numbers without the digit 7 which is $6^4 = 1296$

But then I don't really know where to start to find the probability they ask.

Comment: Don't subtract those without double number from the total $7^4$.  Subtract them from the total without $7$s or the $6^4$.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product#:%7E:text=In%20combinatorics%2C%20the%20rule%20of,ways%20of%20performing%20both%20actions.), for each of three cases; the first case is that the first repeat digit occurs in the second placement, the second case is that the first repeat digit occurs in the third placement, and the third case is that the first repeat digit occurs in the fourth placement, the desired probability is:

$$ \frac{6 \times 1 \times 6 \times 6\ +\ 6 \times 5 \times 2 \times 6\ +\ 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3}{7^4}. $$

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach:

$$\frac{6^4 - \left[\binom{6}{4} \times 4!\right]}{7^4}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the denominator represents the total number of ways of forming any $(4)$ digit number, sampling with replacement, where order of selection is deemed relevant.

In (1) above, the first term in the numerator represents the corresponding number of ways of forming any $(4)$ digit number, when the digit $(7)$ is excluded.

In (1) above, the second term in the numerator represents that you must deduct those $(4)$ digit numbers, where $(7)$ is excluded, and $(4)$ distinct digits are selected.

Answer (score 1):

First look at the options without any 7. There are 1296 of these. There are 15 possible combinations of 4 distinct digits, each of which has 24 arrangements. Therefore, the number of possible combinations is 1296 - (15)(24), which is 936. Therefore, the answer is $936/2401$.

Comment: Sorry might look dumb asking this but how did you find 15 possible combinations and 24 arrangements ?

Comment: I used the formulas for the choose function and 4! for the number of arrangements.

Comment: What is the formula of the choose function ?

Comment: n!/(k!(n-k)!) is the formula.

Comment: should we not use the formula n!/(n-r)! because i think the order matters no ?

Comment: Oh, I was being a little inefficient. Thanks.

Comment: so the answer is 1296-(6!/2!) = 936 ? because 6!/(6-4)! = 360

Comment: The number of favorable cases is $6^4 - P(6, 4) = 1296 - 360 = 936$.  The probability is $936/2401$.

Comment: Might be easier to think in these terms.  The number of ways to have $4$ distinct elements (none of them $7$) is to consider $6$ options for the first position, $5$ for the second and so on.  $\frac {6!}{(6-4)!}=P(6,4)$.  This answer is considering there are ${6\choose 4} = \frac {6!}{4!2!}=15$ ways to choice the four digits in any order, and then there are $4!=24$ ways to choose the order but... why do the work twice.  Why remove the order just to put it back? This shows that $P(n,r)={n\choose r}\times r!=\frac {n!}{(n-r)!r!}\times r!$ but.... isn't $P(n,r)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ more basic?